# Folder not seen by web server

Tags: html, apache, web, server

I'm running Apache2 on Ubuntu 16.04.
For some reason, there's a single folder that is not being seen by Apache (if it's even an Apache problem).
[Sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjaG9.png)

On the left is the directory and on the right is what's being seen. Everything except the folder "7.10.1" is seen. I've tried renaming and restarting the apache server with no luck. I'm not sure what's going on here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you checked the folder permissions?

Comment: @YogeshChauhan Yes. I have full permissions on all of the folders

Comment: Do cross these points as well:
1. Change Folder name, refresh the browser window
2. Check for hidden folder 
3. Folder Permissions to 755
4. Change browser

Comment: @YogeshChauhan I got it working, Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it working now.
This is what I did:

1. Created new folder named "123"
2. Copied files from "7.10.1" folder and pasted inside "123" folder
3. Deleted "7.10.1" folder
4. Renamed "123" folder to "7.10.1"

Not sure why this was happening considering all folders came from the same .tgz file. I even re-downloaded and re-extracted the .tgz file. Weird.